Overleaf Community on Windows
I would like to install Overleaf Community on a Windows machine, but the instructions provided on the github website only apply specifically to Linux.
Here is the link:
https://github.com/overleaf/toolkit/blob/master/doc/quick-start-guide.md
Can anyone help me carrying the process out, but on Windows?
Many thanks!

Welcome. // Sounds like a good question for Overleaf ... I.e. it's hardly related to Latex as defined for this community.

It's not on topic here but i don't think it's possible to run linux docker containers directly on windows you would need a linux vm or some other layer see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers
